# Invertible system for the eigenfunction $x[n]=e^{j\omega n}$

Tags: discrete-signals, linear-systems, z-transform

I was doing some calculations in my LTI systems course and I stumbled in an interesting question I wasn't really sure how to answer so I'd appreciate any direction or solution you can give me:

I'm trying to determine whether there's an invertible system $g[n]$ that will satisfy the equation:

$$e^{j\omega_0 n} \star g[n]= \delta[n],$$ whereas $\omega_0$=constant and the symbol $\star$ represents convolution.

usually it is common to see the signal $e^{j\omega_0 n}u[n]$, then I could easily use Z transform to get
$$Z\{e^{j\omega_0 n}u[n]\}=1/(1-e^{j\omega_0}z^{-1})$$ and solve that $$G(z)=1-e^{j\omega_0}z^{-1}$$ (and it exists because they have shared ROC) and find $$g[n]=\delta[n]-e^{j\omega_0}\delta[n-1]$$ from there resulting in $$e^{j\omega_0n}u[n] \star (\delta[n]-e^{j\omega_0}\delta[n-1])=\delta[n].$$

but how can I determine if such an invertible system exists when the $u[n]$ is missing?

Comment: It would be really very helpful if you formatted your formulas using Latex.

Comment: Oh my favorite function!

Answer (score 1):

So you're looking for an LTI system with impulse response $g[n]$ with the property

$$e^{j\omega_0n}*g[n]=\delta[n]$$

**Hint:**
Note that the input has a single frequency, whereas the output contains all frequencies. Now combine that with an important property of (stable) LTI systems, and the answer should be obvious.

Comment: I'm still new at this so I'd appreciate if you could explain further since I'm not following yet, thanks alot!

Comment: A linear and time-invariant system cannot create frequency components in its output that do not exist in its input.